# "update-initramfs -u" does not work in external SSD booted Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so I can't turn off nouveau driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, initramfs, nouveau

I use Ubuntu 22.04 in external SSD for Windows7 PC with nvidia geforce gtx960 GPU

I wanted to install Nvidia driver(Driver version is Linux X64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver 535.129.03) and turn off nouveau driver. So after I blacklisted nouveau driver (wrote `'blacklist nouveau'` and `'options nouveau modeset=0'` in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf), I tried `update-initramfs -u`. But Ubuntu returned `update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media`

I also tried to use `update-initramfs.distrib -u`, and cuz it seems to work, I installed nvidia driver, but `nvidia-smi` returns N`VIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running`

Are there anyway to make `update-initramfs -u` work, or to install Nvidia driver successfully?

Comment: Don't  blacklist the nouveau driver. It's a failsafe open source graphics driver in case the proprietary Nvidia driver can't boot. Otherwise your computer will use the proprietary Nvidia driver if it is installed.

Comment: Is the drive mounted read-only as the error suggests? You can check with the `mount` command (there will be an entry like `/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (ro)` if it is)

Comment: @dom1310df it seems to be rw, not read-only